# Doesn't dispose() method of ConnectionMultiplexer flushes all keys and the redis database it is connected to?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have cached my database using Redis. When I run dispose() method on instance of redis's connectionmultiplexer class, it does not flushes out keys and the database.

```
---
 private static ConnectionMultiplexer _conn;
private static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {

                    //Close & Dispose Old connection
                    if (_connection != null)
                    {
                           _conn.Close(false);
                           _conn.Dispose();
                           _conn = null;
                    }

                   ---
                   ---

                    return _conn;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question:** What exactly this dispose() method do then? Shouldn't it flush out and clear all redis database which are connected to `_conn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dispose(...) operation on the ConnectionMultiplexer closes the connections and releases other resources like ServerEndpoint objects associated with the ConnectionMultiplexer object. it doesn't issue any commands to Redis.

The sources are here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs

Answer (score 3):

Why should the client ever flush Redis automatically??

The thing would not be usable by anyone actually using it as a distributed cache (many connected clients using the shared cache...).

Redis has a `FLUSH` and `FLUSHALL` command which work per server, you can explicitly call those.

See 
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysScan.md